# Keyboard shortcut for zoom in Adobe Reader (Mac) fails

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-reader, zoom

1. Suppose *Adobe Reader* is closed.
2. When opening the programme again, the keyboard shortcut does not work at first.
3. Then when (and only when) one changes the zoom manually, by selecting from the drop-down-box a zoom-percentage, functions the keyboard-shortcut thereafter (until the application is closed).

Why is this happening? What is wrong with this programme or my computer?

I have tried reinstalling, updating, etc., but the problem still remains.

Sys: OSX 10.9.1, Adobe Reader 11.0.4(also with previous versions).

Comment: Define "closed" and "opening again". By closing, do you mean closing the document window, or exiting the entire application? Same for opening—are you opening it by clicking on the dock icon?

Comment: "closed" = the entire application is completely exited;
"opening" = launching it.
I would other have said "docking"/"hiding".